# Mongodb Wildcard Searching without regex

Tags: node.js, mongodb, wildcard

I can see Wildcard Operator in https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/wildcard.
Can anyone share how exactly this is used.

Consider user model as
user = { 'email': 'jibrish@gmail.com', ...}

i tried

```
db.users.aggregate([{"$search":{"wildcard": { "path": "email", "query": "*"}}},{"$project":{"email": 1}}])
```

But this returns empty array!!

Comment: What pattern are you trying to match?

Comment: Do you have index on email field?

Comment: Yes, I do have index on email field @gibbs

Comment: @codemonkey In this example, * pattern should return all users right?. But it return empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comment, that's the problem

You need to have index on `parh` field.

As in the documentation

> Indexed field or fields to search. You can also specify a wildcard path to search. See path construction for more information.

Comment: I tried indexing right now. But still its returning empty array.

Comment: Could you try different patterns and please add the results of explain query.

Comment: I have tried different patterns of wildcard searching. Like
db.users.aggregate([{"$search":{"wildcard": { "path": "email", "query": "mis*"}}},{"$project":{"email": 1}}])  
which is supposed to give all emails starting with "mis". But all those are returning same empty array.

Comment: Can you add the results of explain query.

Comment: "stages" : [
  {
   "$_internalSearchBetaMongotRemote" : {
    "mongotQuery" : {
     "wildcard" : {
      "path" : "email",
      "query" : "mis*"
     }
    },
    "explain" : {

    }
   }
  },
  {
   "$_internalSearchBetaIdLookup" : {

   }
  },
  {
   "$project" : {
    "_id" : true,
    "email" : true
   }
  }
 ],
 "serverInfo" : {
  "host" : "atlas-uic44s-shard-00-01.scgfr.mongodb.net",
  "port" : 27000,
  "version" : "4.2.11",
  "gitVersion" : "ea38428f0c6742c7c2c7f677e73d79e17a2aab96"
 },
 "ok" : 1,

Comment: Can you look for ixscan or collscan in that result.